# Create low and high range with case statement

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following case statement against my borrowers table

```
SELECT borrower_id,
   CASE
     WHEN bo.fico_score >= 0 AND bo.fico_score <= 599 THEN '0-599'
     WHEN bo.fico_score >= 600 AND bo.fico_score <= 649 THEN '600-649'
     WHEN bo.fico_score >= 650 AND bo.fico_score <= 699 THEN '650-699'
     WHEN bo.fico_score >= 700 AND bo.fico_score <= 749 THEN '700-749'
     WHEN bo.fico_score >= 750 AND bo.fico_score <= 800 THEN '750-800'
     WHEN bo.fico_score > 800 AND bo.fico_score <= 850 THEN '801-850'
   END AS "Borrower FICO"
from borrowers bo;
```

The use case requires I provide a low range and high range instead of the above. The code below works.

```
SELECT borrower_id,
   CASE
     WHEN bo.fico_score >= 0 AND bo.fico_score <= 599 THEN '0'
     WHEN bo.fico_score >= 600 AND bo.fico_score <= 649 THEN '600'
     WHEN bo.fico_score >= 650 AND bo.fico_score <= 699 THEN '650'
     WHEN bo.fico_score >= 700 AND bo.fico_score <= 749 THEN '700'
     WHEN bo.fico_score >= 750 AND bo.fico_score <= 800 THEN '750'
     WHEN bo.fico_score > 800 AND bo.fico_score <= 850 THEN '801'
   END AS "Borrower FICO LOW",
   CASE
     WHEN bo.fico_score >= 0 AND bo.fico_score <= 599 THEN '599'
     WHEN bo.fico_score >= 600 AND bo.fico_score <= 649 THEN '649'
     WHEN bo.fico_score >= 650 AND bo.fico_score <= 699 THEN '699'
     WHEN bo.fico_score >= 700 AND bo.fico_score <= 749 THEN '749'
     WHEN bo.fico_score >= 750 AND bo.fico_score <= 800 THEN '800'
     WHEN bo.fico_score > 800 AND bo.fico_score <= 850 THEN '850'
   END AS "Borrower FICO HIGH",
from borrowers bo;
```

I don't think it is very good design. Is there a better way to write this case statement so I can provide a low and high range for a borrower credit score?

Comment: If you are using strings, why not just do something like `'600-649'`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff   This is what I had in my original query but the requirements have been changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your original query and split the resulting strings by '-', e.g.:

```
with borrowers(borrower_id, fico_score) as (
values
    (1, 133),
    (2, 633)
)

select 
    borrower_id, 
    split_part(fico, '-', 1) as "Borrower FICO Low",
    split_part(fico, '-', 2) as "Borrower FICO High"
from (
    select borrower_id,
       case
         when bo.fico_score >= 0 and bo.fico_score <= 599 then '0-599'
         when bo.fico_score >= 600 and bo.fico_score <= 649 then '600-649'
         when bo.fico_score >= 650 and bo.fico_score <= 699 then '650-699'
         when bo.fico_score >= 700 and bo.fico_score <= 749 then '700-749'
         when bo.fico_score >= 750 and bo.fico_score <= 800 then '750-800'
         when bo.fico_score > 800 and bo.fico_score <= 850 then '801-850'
       end as fico
    from borrowers bo
    ) s;

 borrower_id | Borrower FICO Low | Borrower FICO High 
-------------+-------------------+--------------------
           1 | 0                 | 599
           2 | 600               | 649
(2 rows)
```